# Ruby convert time to integer and then back. Keeps adding an hour

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, time

In my rails app, I'm trying to convert the time to an integer, and then convert it back. However, when I do this, it switches time zones and it screws me up.

Here's the start and stop schedule that I have:

```
[8] pry(#<Campaign>)> random_schedule[0]
=> 2018-10-05 21:10:00 -0600
[9] pry(#<Campaign>)> random_schedule[1]
=> 2018-10-05 21:20:00 -0600
```

Now what I'm trying to do is select a random time in between those times. I'm doing that by doing this:

```
start = random_schedule[0].to_i
stop = random_schedule[1].to_i

selected_time = rand(start..stop)
selected_schedule = Time.at(selected_time)
```

However, this then turns into this:

```
[1] pry(#<Campaign>)> selected_schedule
=> 2018-10-05 22:16:17 -0500
```

and so now it keeps queuing it up for an hour ahead of time, although it should be occuring in just a few minutes.

What am I doing wrong here? The `.zone` of `selected_schedule`, `random_schedule[0]`, and `random_schedule[1]` all show as `CDT` but one is -0500 and the other is 0600, so something is obviously off.

**EDIT**

So here's a much deeper issue that I'm seeing. If I look into the Model, I can see that the created/updated times are using CDT, but the other fields are using CST. How is this possible?

```
=> #<campaign_schedule:0x00007fa8de3ea4e8
 id: 8,
 campaign_id: 8,
 start_date: Fri, 05 Oct 2018,
 start_time: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 22:05:00 CST -06:00,
 stop_date: Fri, 05 Oct 2018,
 stop_time: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 22:10:00 CST -06:00,
 created_at: Fri, 05 Oct 2018 21:49:46 CDT -05:00,
 updated_at: Fri, 05 Oct 2018 21:49:46 CDT -05:00>
```

My form looks like this:

```
<%= campaign_schedule.date_field :start_date, as: :date, value: campaign_schedule.object.try(:strftime,"%m/%d/%Y"), class: 'form-control' %>
```

and when it saves, it's saving as CST, which is throwing things off by an hour for me.

So on a new form, I have this in the controller, which builds the campaign:

```
  # app/controllers/campaigns_controller.rb
  # GET /campaigns/new
  def new
    @campaign = Campaign.new
    @campaign.build_campaign_schedule.campaign_schedule_hours.build
  end
```

and on the campaign form, here's what it looks like:

```
<%= form_with(model: @campaign, local: true, html: {role: "form", id: "campaign_form"}) do |form| %>
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="tabs-container">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#basics"><i class="fas fa-cogs"></i> Basics</a></li>
            <li class=""><a data-toggle="tab" href="#schedule"><i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i> Schedule</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="basics" class="tab-pane active">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <%= form.fields_for :campaign_schedule do |campaign_schedule| %>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-sm-5">
                            <%= label_tag "What day and time should the campaign start?" %>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <%= campaign_schedule.date_field :start_date, as: :date, value: Time.now.strftime("%m/%d/%Y"), class: 'form-control' %>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <%= campaign_schedule.time_field :start_time, as: :time, value: Time.now.strftime( "%I:%M %p"), class: "form-control" %>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

and when it saves, this is the save action in the controller:

```
  # POST /campaigns
  # POST /campaigns.json
  def create
    @campaign = Campaign.new(campaign_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @campaign.save
        review_campaign_schedule
        format.html { redirect_back fallback_location: campaigns_path, notice: 'Campaign was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @campaign }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @campaign.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

However, when I go back and call that Campaign.start_date, it's CST and not CDT. Even when I'm doing it directly from the rails console, it's using CST and not CDT. Is it something with the builder? Check this out:

```
[8] pry(#<CampaignsController>)> @campaign = Campaign.new
=> #<Campaign:0x00007fa8ef5bbab8 id: nil, name: nil, completed_date: nil, status: "Scheduled", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
[9] pry(#<CampaignsController>)> @campaign.build_campaign_schedule.campaign_schedule_hours.build    
=> #<CampaignscheduleHour:0x00007fa8e6377be8 id: nil, campaign_schedule_id: nil, day: nil, start_hours: nil, stop_hours: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
[11] pry(#<CampaignsController>)> @campaign.campaign_schedule
=> #<Campaignschedule:0x00007fa8ef5b07d0 id: nil, campaign_id: nil, start_date: nil, start_time: nil, stop_date: nil, stop_time: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
[12] pry(#<CampaignsController>)> @campaign.campaign_schedule.start_time = "22:30"
=> "22:30"
[13] pry(#<CampaignsController>)> @campaign.campaign_schedule.start_time
=> Sat, 01 Jan 2000 22:30:00 CST -06:00
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your initial time from `random_schedule` does not take into account Daylight Saving Time offset (DST). You can test it with `random_schedule[0].dst?`

Currently correct offset for CDT timezone is -0500, DST is on:

https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/cdt

So when converting your time back with `Time.at(selected_time)` command it converts to canonical form.

Comment: Think I've figured out a much deeper issue here. Rails is actually showing CDT in my created/update record attributes, making me believe that CDT is enabled. However, the forms are saving the dates and times as CST, which makes no sense to me. If Rails is configured with daylight savings time, why aren't the forms? Very strange.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by ```the forms are saving the dates and times as CST```. Maybe it's database settings?

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect some output from the rails console. My models all seem to be using the correct time zone when creating and updating, but its other attributes (outside of created_at/updated_at) are all in CST instead of CDT. Hope I'm explaining this right.

Comment: As I see, ```start_date``` is ok, but the timezone-problem is with ```start_time```. How do you handle it? Can you show template and controller code which saves it?

Comment: Updated. Thanks for your help. Hopefully getting closer :)

Comment: Thank you. However it is still not clear how time becomes date. In your template default value for ```start_time``` field is ```Time.now.strftime("%I:%M %p")```, which gives you time in *10:17 PM* format. However, in your model ```start_tame``` becomes a timestamp *Sat, 01 Jan 2000 22:17:00 CST -06:00* . So I wonder where that date part of ```start_time``` comes from.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181377/discussion-between-lewlsauce-and-ilya-konyukhov).